# CODEFORCES 1744B, how could I fix runtime error?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, time

I'm trying to solve the next problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1744/problem/B
When  I run the code in my terminal, it works with the example given in the exercise; but it doesn't when I submit it in CodeForces, it cause a runtime error which I cannot figure out.

```
def increment(arr, length, option, add):
    for i in range(length):
        if(option == '0') and (arr[i]%2 == 0):
            arr[i] += add
        elif(option == '1') and (arr[i]%2 != 0):
            arr[i] += add
        else:
            pass
    return arr
 
def main():
    quantityOperation = int(input())
    while quantityOperation > 0:
        length, times = input().split()
        length = int(length)
        times = int(times)
        arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
        
        while times > 0:
            opt, add = input().split()
            add = int(add)
            res = sum(increment(arr, length, opt, add))
            print(res)
            times -= 1
    quantityOperation -= 1
 
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop inside your main function doesn't end. You should put `quantityOperation -= 1` inside the while loop.

---

However, your code will still become time limit exceeded after fixing this. The correct idea is to precalculate odd and even sum and modify them according to the queries instead of looping all elements inside increment function every time. You can check the [editorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/108101) for this problem.